# Facebook API login and Permission Request in Lightbox. Is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've been researching this for a while now and cant get a straight answer.

Is it possible to have the login and/or the Permission Request show in a Lightbox overlay rather than a pop up using the Facebook API?

Thanks for the help,

- Dane

**UPDATE** - When launching the permissions popup in a lightbox overlay Facebook breaks the operation and all you see is the Facebook logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no. Facebook doesn't allow much integration with their forms because it opens up the ability to find loopholes, and for a company that big a loophole is basically 9/11 for them.

Comment: hmmm, even if its in a iframe? then it shouldn't matter how it is displayed?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could put a iframe inside the lightbox. But you cannot change the format UNLESS you use javascript to change the innerhtml.